Why did the lmr51430XFDDCR get fried?
I used the LMR51430XFDDCR as a DC/DC power converter on my PCB. Upon connecting a fully charged 3-cell LiPo battery (12.5V), the converter instantly failed. The PCB is designed to draw no more than 2.5A, while the converter can supply up to 3A. Additionally, the IC is rated for a maximum input voltage of 40V, which is well above the 12.5V from the battery. I used TI's WEBENCH Power Designer to create the schematic and followed the layout guidelines provided in the datasheet. The PCB is made of 4 layers(upper layer: signal, in1: GND, in2: 3.3V and the forth layer, on the other side is also signal). Given these precautions, I don't know why the IC was damaged.



Reference
Part




C24
CL10A475KO8NNNC


C26
GRM188R71H104KA93D


C30
GRM155R71C104KA88D


L3
744314650


R7
CRCW0402162KFKED


R8
CRCW040222K1FKED


C32
GRM32ER61C476KE15L




The TI's recommendation for the lmr51430XFDDCR:

My layout:

The GND pour:

The inductor characteristics:

The copper pour on the top layer:

The GND plane(second layer):

The 3.3V layer:

The signal layer on the bottom:


@winny The PCB is made up of 4 layers. The upper layer is signal, after GND, 3.3V and the forth layer on the other side is also signal.

@winny I've edited my question.  The saturation current on the inductor is 6.6A.

Is it possible the PCB has an inrush current that could cause the IC to fail on startup?

Could you add 2µ2F on C26 and try again?

@InBedded16 I don't know if it's possible because I calculated a max current draw of 2.6A with 3 SG90 servos (750mA each) + MCU(stm32f405rgt6 + BMI088 + BMP280 and + external flash memory. Initially when I connected the battery the servos weren't even connected to the PCB.

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer do you mean to add a 2uF2 in parallel with C26 or to replace C26 with a 2uF2 cap?

You haven't provided specs for your passives. Can you do that, or alternatively double check yourself that your capacitors are rated for the voltage they're being subjected to?

Also is there a reason you didn't follow the suggested values for 5V output as found on page 16 of the datasheet? ie R_fbt=100k and R_fbb=13.7k, and C_out = 2x 22uF caps? Your R_fbt is technically out of the recommended range, although I strongly doubt that is the root of the problem.

@InBedded16 I've edited the initial post and I've added a list with all the parts. I have checked every component and each one is rated for at least 16V.  I didn't follow the datasheet because I used the WEBENCH power designer from TI that made the schematic for me.

@Robert interesting. Well you may want to pump those capacitors up to 25V ratings. Just because a capacitor is rated for 16V does not mean it is effective up to that voltage, the datasheet for C24 is a good example. Check page 14, it shows you that by 75% of the rated voltage the C_delta is 70%. So your input/output capacitors may not be doing much. I think your next step should be to gather oscilloscope readings for as many pins/nodes as you can measure and post/analyze them.

Consider this answer and the linked questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/713381/correct-placement-of-series-ferrite-beads-to-avoid-dc-disconnect-during-power-cy/713473#713473

@Robert I meant replacing 1µF with 2µ2F. If you don't want to remove the 1µF cap, you could solder another one ontop.

@InBedded16 thank you for the help! I will make another PCB with only the DC/DC converter and it's external circuit and I will use only components with much higher voltage ratings to see what I get. Also could you please send me a link to the exact datasheet for the C24?

@Robert there probably isn't one, I was using the generic datasheet for that company's capacitors that comes up when you search the C24 part number. 25V should be sufficient but no harm in stepping up to 35V or 50V either. I would also strongly advise you to try to get those O-Scope captures before you redesign the PCB, without knowing which node(s) are behaving incorrectly you can't know if you're solving the actual issue or chasing a red herring.

@InBedded16 Thank you again for all the help!

@TimWilliams Thank you very much for the help! It took me a while to understand the answer, but after going over it a few time, I think this has to be the problem in my circuit, especially since I use a ferrite bead at the input which also has an inductance.
